# How to get input variable from other function while running pytest for SeleniumBase in Python?

Tags: python, selenium, pytest, python-unittest, seleniumbase

The file I upload to a website changes with each run, and I'd like a way to change it in the test method. Currently, I have it set up like this:

**functions.py**

```
def get_file():
    ...
    file = file_ex1.doc
    return file

def run_test1():
    cmd = "pytest -v webtests.py::EF --browser=chrome"
    subprocess.run(split(cmd))  # run command line
...
```

**webtests.py**

```
file_path = file  # changes with each run, should come from get_file()

class EF(BaseCase):
    def test_now(self):
        self.open('https://www...')
        self.find_element('input[name="Query"]').send_keys(file_path)`
```

I was wondering about the best way to change the `file_path` variable based on the output of certain functions in functions.py. For example, it could sometimes produce a file called file1 to upload, or another time filet2.txt. What's the best way to connect the two scripts and run test_now() with the updated file path for each run? Or should they be set up in a different way?

Thanks so much in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> You can use the pytest args that come with SeleniumBase.

```
--data=DATA  # (Extra test data. Access with "self.data" in tests.)
--var1=DATA  # (Extra test data. Access with "self.var1" in tests.)
--var2=DATA  # (Extra test data. Access with "self.var2" in tests.)
--var3=DATA  # (Extra test data. Access with "self.var3" in tests.)
```

Source: [Docs](https://seleniumbase.io/)